# Stylus not parsing all variables in the same way

Tags: stylus

I'm trying to parse a list in Stylus (latest version), but it's having odd results.

```
$small  = 200px
$medium = 400px
$large  = 600px

$list = small  $small,
        medium $medium,
        large  $large

for ham in $list
  @media screen and (min-width: ham[1])
    .{ham[0]}
      width ham[1]
```

yields

```
@media screen and (min-width: ham[1]) {
  .small {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: ham[1]) {
  .medium {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: ham[1]) {
  .large {
    width: 600px;
  }
}
```

The `ham[1]` variable isn't getting parsed in the media query regardless of whether I wrap it in {} or not, but it's parsed elsewhere just fine. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, media queries do not allow for interpolation. What you can do however is use *one* variable. Just construct the query beforehand for now :

```
$small  = 200px
$medium = 400px
$large  = 600px

$list = small  $small,
        medium $medium,
        large  $large

for ham in $list
  query = 'screen and (min-width: %s)' % ham[1]
  @media query
    .{ham[0]}
      width ham[1]
```

UPDATE :
With Stylus 0.44 (or 0.45), they now do !